# How to make a 3D list from a txt file? python

Tags: python, list

I've been stuck on this for almost 3 days now, and I have tried so many different ways, but none of them worked!

The txt file (num.txt) looks like:

```
1234
4321
3214
3321
4421
2341
```

How can I put this file into a 3D list made up of 2 rows and 3 columns?

The output I am trying to achieve is:

```
[ [['1','2','3','4']['4','3','2','1']['3','2','1','4']], [['3','3','2','1']['4','4','2','1']['2','3','4','1']] ]
```

(I've spaced it out a little more in an attempt to make it easier to see!)

I thought it would be similar to making a 2D list, but nothing I tried worked! Can anyone please help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to open the file and type-cast each string of line to `list` like:

```
my_list = []
sublist_size = 3

with open('/path/to/num.txt') as f:
    file_lines = list(f)
    for i in range(0, len(file_lines), sublist_size):
        my_list.append([list(line.rstrip()) for line in file_lines[i:i+sublist_size]])
        #                           ^ Remove `\n` from right of each line
```

Here `my_list` will hold the value you desire:

```
[[['1','2','3','4']['4','3','2','1']['3','2','1','4']],
 [['3','3','2','1']['4','4','2','1']['2','3','4','1']]]
```

Comment: Don't forget to `.strip()` the `'\n'` from the end of each `line`

Comment: No, at least for me in Python 2.7, the newlines are included in each `line`

Comment: [`.readlines()`](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/06/readlines-considered-silly.html) is not necessary and in fact bogs down the processing -> `for line in f` is sufficient as it then treats the file as an iterator and processes it as needed

Comment: @TemporalWolf: Thanks for the information. Updated it. In fact I do not need `readlines()`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very simple way to do it with some easy arithmetic:

```
with open('num.txt') as infile:  # open file
    answer = []
    for i,line in enumerate(infile):  # get the line number (starting at 0) and the actual line
        if not i%3: answer.append([])
        answer[-1].append(list(line.strip()))
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that for sufficiently large files this approach becomes almost mandatory, as it does not require loading the entire file into memory.

Comment: @TemporalWolf: that's debatable, unless you wanted to make a generator to yield each triple of lines, because `answer` grows to hold the entire file anyways. If OP really wants a list of triples of file lines, then it might help (very slightly) to use tuples instead of lists, inside `answer` to save on space

Comment: Both of the other answers **require loading the entire file before working on it**. Your solution can be used to save out the result periodically and thereby process files which cannot be held entirely in memory. This uses two iterators and python's intelligent file buffer.

Answer (score 1):

The solution using `range()` function and simple *list comprehension*:

```
with open('./text_files/num.txt', 'r') as fh:  # change to your current file path
    l = [list(l.strip()) for l in fh]

n = 3   # chunk size
result = [l[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(l), n)]  # splitting into chunks of size 3
print(result)
```

The output:

```
[[['1', '2', '3', '4'], ['4', '3', '2', '1'], ['3', '2', '1', '4']], [['3', '3', '2', '1'], ['4', '4', '2', '1'], ['2', '3', '4', '1']]]
```

Comment: [.readlines()](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/06/readlines-considered-silly.html) is not necessary and slows down the process, since it reads the entire file and parses it before returning. `for l in fh` returns an iterator that returns lines as needed.

Comment: @TemporalWolf, ok, removed that. Thanks for the hint

Answer (score 0):

Another options which I think is clearer and does not require loading the entire file into memory:

```
inner_size = 3
inner_range = range(inner_size)  # precompute this since we'll be using it a lot
with open('/home/user/nums.txt') as f:
    result = []
    try:
        while True:
            subarr = []
            for _ in inner_range:
                subarr.append(list(f.next().rstrip()))
            result.append(subarr)
    except StopIteration:
        pass
```

Using the built-in `__iter__` on the file object, we build sub arrays and append them onto the resultant array, and use the `StopIteration` exception to know we're finished, discarding any extra data. You could easily `if subarr: result.append(subarr)` in the exception if you want to keep any partial subarr at the end.

Written as a list comprehension (although without the ability to recover any final, partial sublist):

```
inner_size = 3
inner_range = range(inner_size)
with open('/home/user/nums.txt') as f:
    result = []
    try:
        while True:
            result.append([list(f.next().rstrip()) for _ in inner_range])
    except StopIteration:
        pass
```